# YaST broken after removing PCRE 7.9

Tags: opensuse, autoyast

I installed PCRE 8.12 on my server using YaST but found that PCRE 7.9 was still installed and active (as seen via pcretest -C). In order to delete or deactive PCRE 7.9 I tried deleting it using YaST. But I think that process deleted many other files which were needed for YaST to properly run. Now, YaST is broken. When I start YaST in my terminal and select+enter 'Software Management' or any other option, error like following appears:

```
# yast
Can't locate Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /y2update/modules /root/.yast2/modules /usr/share/YaST2/modules /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.1/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.1/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.1/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.1 .) at /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.1/diagnostics.pm line 195.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.1/diagnostics.pm line 195.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.1/i586-linux-thread-multi/YaST/YCP.pm line 119.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.1/i586-linux-thread-multi/YaST/YCP.pm line 119.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/YaST2/modules/URLRecode.pm line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/YaST2/modules/URLRecode.pm line 16.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
y2base: perl.c:542: perl_destruct: Assertion `(my_perl->Iscopestack_ix) == 1' failed.
YaST got signal 6 at YCP file /usr/share/YaST2/clients/sw_single.ycp:25
/sbin/yast: line 399: 30680 Aborted $ybindir/y2base $module "$@" "$SELECTED_GUI" $Y2_GEOMETRY $Y2UI_ARGS
```

Following info might be useful:

I am using opensuse 11.3 (x86_64)

```
# zypper lr
# | Alias | Name | Enabled | Refresh
--+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+--------
1 | Updates for openSUSE 11.3 11.3-1.82 | Updates for openSUSE 11.3 11.3-1.82 | Yes | Yes 
2 | download.opensuse.org-oss | Main Repository (Sources) | Yes | Yes 
3 | download.opensuse.org-perl | openSUSE BuildService - devel:languageserl | Yes | Yes 
4 | download.opensuse.org-php | openSUSE BuildService - PHP | Yes | Yes 
5 | openSUSE_11.3 | openSUSE_11.3 | Yes | Yes 
6 | repo-non-oss | openSUSE-11.3-Non-Oss | Yes | Yes 
7 | repo-oss | openSUSE-11.3-Oss | Yes | Yes
```

I have already done `zypper up`

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling perl.
[Here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=34305) is the solution of similar problems for Arch Linux

Comment: This din work for me. YaST still broken.

Comment: Installing perl-base-32bit solved the problem. :)